# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)

Tags: php, amazon-aws, phpmailer, smtp, elastic-beanstalk

Estou a usar o AWS Elastic Beanstalk e não consigo enviar mails com o PHPMailer. No meu servidor local funciona direitinho com exatamente a mesma configuração. O AWS Elastic Beanstalk usa o Red Hat 4.8.3-9... Eu tentei todas [as técnicas de resolução de problemas do PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) e todas estão a funcionar normalmente. A única que me deixa dúvidas é a "SELinux blocking" que não sei se será um problema, mas de qualquer forma o erro nem é o mesmo.

Eu tentei usar o comando `getsebool httpd_can_sendmail` e a resposta foi essa `getsebool:  SELinux is disabled`.

O erro do PHPMailer:

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)

Será que o problema é este? Alguém sabe como resolver?

Cross Post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42983283/1817673
Issue: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1013

Comment: Subnet tem internet gateway?

Comment: @juniorb2ss subnet de onde?

Comment: Boa tarde! Eu estava com o mesmo erro, estava usando a porta 587, troquei para 465 e funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)" significa que não houve conexão com o servidor SMTP, isso significa que existe um bloqueio de conexão, revise as seguintes questões:

- Certifique-se de que o endereço de host ou ip sejam válidos;
- Certifique-se de que a porta inserida e forma de autenticação estejam corretas; (normalmente 587 sem TLS/SSL ou 465 caso tenha suporte a TLS/SSL)
- Certifique-se de que seu firewall local ou remoto NÃO esteja bloqueando as conexões, portanto é viável revisar as regras de ambos firewall;
- Certifique-se que o servidor SMTP permite uma conexão externa, alguns provedores bloqueiam conexões externas;