# Problemas com PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

eu estou testando o script php que envia emails usando PHPMailer pelo WAMP com as credenciais corretas do meu SMTP, só que toda a vez que eu abro o php pelo wamp ele diz que é impossível enviar o email e conectar-se ao smtp. Como faço para corrigir isso?

Erro:

```
2018-01-10 01:47:12 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Nenhuma conexão pode ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente. (10061) 2018-01-10 01:47:12  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Não foi possível enviar o e-mail. Informações do erro: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting.
```

Meu script:
`

```
$Mailer = new PHPMailer();

$Mailer->IsSMTP();
$Mailer->IsHTML(true);
$Mailer->Charset= 'UTF-8';
$Mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
$Mailer->SMTPAuth = true;


// Configuracoes smtp
$Mailer->Host = 'smtp.xxx.com.br';
$Mailer->Port = 578;
$Mailer->Username = 'xxx@xxx.com.br';
$Mailer->Password = 'supersecreta';

// remetente
$Mailer->From = 'xxx@xxx.com.br';
$Mailer->FromName = "Nome";
$Mailer->Subject = "Assunto";

//corpo
$Mailer->Body = '-=-=- Atendimento -=-=-';
$Mailer->AltBody = 'Este é o corpo da mensagem, teste.';

//destinatario
$Mailer->AddAddress('emaildiferentedofromeusername@hotmail.com');

if($Mailer->Send()) {
   echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
    echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail. ";
    echo "Erro: " . $Mailer->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Grato desde já!

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192302/8063

Comment: voce configurou corretamente o seu php.ini para enviar o email em localhost?

Comment: O open_ssl esta ativo no WAMP?

Comment: O erro está na porta: o correto seria 587.