# SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp

Alguém pode me ajudar, estou a alguns dias tentando solucionar esse erro com o PHPMailed. Já tentei usar 3 scripts diferentes, e sempre mostra **SMTP connect() failed**, já usei a porta **465**, mas deu a mesma coisa... (eu coloquei o "Minha_senha" só aqui, no script tá certo). (Obs: eu já habilitei o login por dispostivos não seguros do gmail).

```
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $email = $_POST['txte'];

    // Instância do objeto PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    // Configura para envio de e-mails usando SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();

    // Servidor SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    // Usar autenticação SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    // Usuário da conta
    $mail->Username = 'leandrorevolve@gmail.com';

    // Senha da conta
    $mail->Password = 'minha_senha';

    // Tipo de encriptação que será usado na conexão SMTP
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    // Porta do servidor SMTP
    $mail->Port = 587;

    // Informa se vamos enviar mensagens usando HTML
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    // Email do Remetente
    $mail->From = 'leandrorevolve@gmail.com';

    // Nome do Remetente
    $mail->FromName = 'Leandro';

    // Endereço do e-mail do destinatário
    $mail->addAddress($email);

    // Assunto do e-mail
    $mail->Subject = 'E-mail PHPMailer';

    // Mensagem que vai no corpo do e-mail
    $mail->Body = '<h1>Mensagem enviada via PHPMailer</h1>';

    // Envia o e-mail e captura o sucesso ou erro
    if($mail->Send()):
        echo 'Enviado com sucesso !';
    else:
        echo 'Erro ao enviar Email:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    endif;
```

Comment: Dá uma [olhada nisso](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/473485-resolvido%C2%A0phpmailer-e-gmail/)

Comment: use `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

Comment: Eu olhei o link, mudei o php.ini e persistiu o mesmo erro. usando "tls" apareceu o seguinte erro: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.

Comment: parece que SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail

Comment: aqui comigo seu codigo funcionou somente trocando `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` com `ssl`não funcionou. Mas meu servidor de email não é gmail

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse post  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89690/envio-de-email-via-phpmailer-para-gmail

Comment: Nesse ultimo link vi um erro, no caso a porta e o SMTPSecure estavam trocados (465 para SSL, e 587 para TLS), porém o erro persiste. O PHP.ini está com a porta 465. (com a 25 o erro persiste). Apliquei o SMTPDebug = 1 e retornou "Failed to connect to server".

Comment: Eu só vejo problemas com gmail. Mais um post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192302/smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server-0?rq=1

Comment: Revisei os itens que o carinha marcou, abri a porta do firewall e mesmo assim continua na mesma..

Comment: Mudei a $port do PHPMailer e do Autoload de 25 para 465 e apareceu: 2018-06-19 01:53:55 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected 2018-06-19 01:53:55 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2018-06-19 01:53:55 SMTP connect() failed.